# Build dynamic bazel target

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-aspect

I would like to build a dynamic target list for my py_binary.

Actually : BUILD.bazel

```
py_binary(
    name = "launch",
    srcs = glob(*.py)
)
```

Supposed : BUILD.bazel

```
load("deps.bzl", "generate_target")

py_binary(
    name = "launch",
    srcs = glob(*.py)
    data = generate_target()    
)
```

Supposed deps.bzl:

```
def generate_target():
     # TODO
```

I got a script python which return my target list just like "["//:target0", "//:target1"...]", depends on config.
Generate_target function, have to use my script python to generate the target list, and return it. But I don't know how can I do.

I try to use a native.genrule, native.py_binary or ctx.actions.run inside generate_target(), but I can't collect my target list.

Someone got an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: More detail, my python script analyzes the yaml config file to determine the correct targets.

Comment: It's not possible to directly execute a binary or script to determine the values in a build file like that -- but there are other techniques like using repository rules to generate build files. It might be useful to update your question to describe what you're trying to accomplish at a very high level

Comment: At the moment, I have a yaml file that tells me which microservices to launch ( python script allows me to retrieve just the targets from yaml). 
However, to launch them, I need to put all my dependencies for each microservice in the "data" part of my py_binary, and I have over a hundred. 
Today, every reference to the microservice is called in the "data" part, even if it hasn't been launched.
I'd like my py_binary to be launched, so that the "data" part is filled in only with services that have been launched.
Thanks for your help, I'm already going to see how the repository rules work.

Comment: I suggest separating the task of "building" from the task of "deploying". Trying to encode deployment information in a build file is not going to be very natural in bazel. You might try creating a script that reads the yaml file, then calls bazel to build the microservices (perhaps using a naming convention to map entries in the yaml file to bazel build targets) then deploys those services.

Comment: The best approach I see is using a Bazel repository rule to read the yaml and generate a separate `py_binary` target for each microservice.